# Start cmd.exe and change directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cd

I'd like a .bat file which is stored on the desktop to perform 2 simple tasks: 
1. Start cmd.exe
2. Change directory to c:\executionsdktest_10.2.2
I have:

```
 @echo off 
 start cmd.exe \k
 cdsdad c:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2
```

But when I double click the .bat file, this starts cmd.exe but cd to c:\users\qestester\desktop. ANy ideas?

Comment: `cdsdad` ? what's that for

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
cmd /k "cd /d c:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2"
```

And you wouldn't need a batch file for that. This can be put in a normal shortcut.

And if you have a normal shortcut you can just specify its working directory and run `cmd` directly without any arguments.

Comment: @Lokiare: Did you use `/c` instead of `/k`?

Comment: is it possible to make the same with powershell?

Comment: @Herrgott: `powershell -NoExit -Command "Set-Location C:\ExecutionSDKText_10.2.2"`. And with a shortcut the working directory still applies.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\Michael && node test.js"
```

What I needed ... was from a localhost page served in PHP, open a terminal, change directory, and start a node script.  Achieved like this:

```
pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
```

.. where $cmd is the first string above.

Comment: That feels like way too many nested `cmd` instances here.

Answer (score 0):

`start cmd.exe /k "C: && cd \ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2"`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to:

- open a command prompt
- change directory (go to another directory)
- run a command from there

solution that worked for me:

```
@echo off
d:
cd\Path\to\wherever
my command
```

**Notes:**

- the `d:` after `@echo off` tells that the path is on the D drive. Write a `c` instead of the `d` and You will be on drive C.
- third line starts with the mandatory `cd`, after which starts the path, with a preceding `\`.
- `my command` can be anything you want, and can contain more that one word (or only one). I used it to run `jupyter notebook`.